# Using a SOCKS proxy from C++

Tags: c++, socks

How I can use a SOCKS proxy from my C++ socket program?

Comment: A title usually "resumes" the question, not the opposite...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

If found these links that *might* help you:

- [A C++ socket library](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html) - Includes an sample of a Web Proxy
- [Another C++ socket library](http://www.alhem.net/project/example2/index.html) - Includes also an example of Proxy

Using [the SOCKS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) and the cited links, you *might* be able to create a SOCKS proxy.

I don't like posting links as an answer but since you don't **clearly** state what you want to achieve, I can't really be more accurate...

Comment: @Navin: Yet 4 people upvoted it and the OP accepted it. It may be useless to you and your particular problem though, in which case I encourage you to post your own specific question (with hopefuly more details than this one).

Comment: I'm using boost's SOCKS client. I barked at your answer because it literally links socket libraries and the SOCKS RFC. I mean, if someone wanted to implement the RFC themselves, they wouldn't come here for links!

Comment: @Navin I was once given a similar answer and implemented a RFC myself. You may consider it useless because you would have liked a "copy-paste" type of answer. Fortunately, some people still want to understand what they do and how things work and reading a RFC can give many clues on how to best solve the problem. Also, if you are so dissatisfied by my answer, why don't you give a better one ? I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: fair enough, removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Here, use the socks wrapper from code project:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Socks.aspx

Comment: You don't need to sign your answers, especially when you have a nickname that can be confusing in a C++ answer ! I spent 5 seconds to figure out what was "0xDEAD BEEF" doing here until i realized it was your nickname ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Socks.aspx - Socks Wrapper