# How to create a basic TCP connection via socks proxy in c++/c?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, socks

I'm looking for a library to add a socks proxy option to a C/C++ program.
What libraries are available for unix and what is the best way to achieve this?

The solution should:

- be considered best practice (safe)
- work in multi-threaded programs with short single-threaded connections
- easy to implement / maintain (if possible)
- work for unix (linux/debian/ubuntu)

Found a lot of information on the internet but nothing specific, and don't know what to use or when to use it.

Comment: excuse my french, corrected

Comment: Probably because of the reasons mentioned in the hover-text of the downvote button.

Comment: I've really researched but even though for someone that knows how to do it, it's simple and easy to find how to do it, I've found it quite hard and thought It would be a good ideea to debate it here so somebody searching for the same thing would find a clear and up-to-date answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this sort of question is off topic, although some [older](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2809559/) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2829637) cover this. There's no shortage of SOCKS library out there, and the protocol itself is fairly simple.

Comment: Didn't know about this, I kind of understand that it would have raised opinionated answers, dough it would be nice for beginners like me to have a way to post this kind of questions in order to get some guidance, and not just go for a random solution found online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do recommend:

- libboost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html
- Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/examples-network.html

Both are multiplatform and very good libraries, but Qt is for GUIs more than a simple library, so think about using libboost for this single purpose.

Comment: it's a very simple program and it has to make a lot of connections. A gui is not needed so libboost sounds good.

Comment: yep, so use libboost: free, open source, cross-platform, and stable, and trustable. Please mark my answer as accepted if you like it :)

Comment: @DídacPérez: Qt is actually only for a small part the GUI, and it's free, open source, cross-platform, and stable. The reason why I'd still prefer boost are not mentioned here, though.

Comment: Yep! I know, actually I use Qt in my daily basis, I didn't tell him to use libboost better than Qt, maybe he can surf and decide which is the best option.